# PHP - Remove a child with a specific attribute selected

Tags: php, removechild

I’m trying to figure out how to remove a child with a specific attribute selected (filename). I have PHP displaying an XML file on a page that loads images. If someone where to click on any image or hit the delete button -

```
<a href=""><img src="' . $child['src'] . '" alt="gallery image" />Delete me</a>
```

it would know where to find in the XML file and delete it.

Here what loads and displays my XML file:

```
<?php 
$xml = simplexml_load_file('myPhotos.xml');
//echo $xml->getName() . "<br />";
foreach ($xml->children() as $child)
{
    echo '<img src="' . $child['src'] . '" alt="gallery image" />';
}
?>
```

Here is my XML structure:

```
<slideshow>
<image src="myPhotosResized/image1.jpg" desc="This is the 1st image!" />
<image src="myPhotosResized/image2.jpg" desc="This is the 2nd image!" />
<image src="myPhotosResized/image3.jpg" desc="This is the 3rd image!" />
<image src="myPhotosResized/image4.jpg" desc="This is the 4th image!" />
</slideshow>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want them to delete it from the DOM (so it disappears in the browser)? Or that it gets deleted from the filesystem?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply! 

I would like it to delete from DOM yes and also i'm realizing now that I want it delete from the file system as well (directory).

Yani helped me, i'm just trying to now figure out how to have on the "deleteFile.php" to delete from DOM.  Seems it's only deleting from directory.

Comment: Just change two things: 1. the `onclick` to be: `deleteFile(this,'.$child["src"].')`, and 2. the function itself to include this new function signature: `function deleteFile(imgObject,filename)` and this internal code: `imgObject.parentNode.removeChild( imgObject );`

Comment: Thank Don!  I got it to work though. I see what you were saying but I just used a little of php instead :) - http://pastie.org/8673164

Comment: Your solution works but requires resending the entire collection and reconstituting the entire DOM. A lot more data sent and processing in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to actually delete the file (and not just remove it from the DOM), either use Ajax or wrap your images with a link that is targeting a script to delete the file:

With Ajax:

```
 <? 
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('myPhotos.xml');
    //echo $xml->getName() . "<br />";
    foreach ($xml->children() as $child)
    {
        echo '<img src="' . $child['src'] . '" alt="gallery image" onclick="deleteFile('.$child["src"].')" />';
    }
    ?>

<script>
function deleteFile(filename) {
    var t = this;
    $.ajax({
            url: 'deleteFile.php?filename='+filename,
            type: 'post',
            success: function(data) {
              t.style.display = 'none';//hide the link 
              alert('File deleted!');
            }
});
}
</script>
```

And on your deleteFile.php you will need to use:

```
$filename = $_GET['filename'];//gets the file name from the URL
unlink($filename);//deletes the file
```

**Second option:**

If you must keep everything with PHP and not use jQuery or Ajax, you can simply wrap the images with a link and set its href to:

```
echo '<a href="deleteFile.php?filename=' . $child["src"] . '"><img src="' . $child['src'] . '" alt="gallery image" /></a>';
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Yani! 

Quick question... on the "deletefile.php" how do I tell it to remove from DOM?

I'm glad you showed me how to remove from directory.  That helps.

Comment: You don't remove it from the DOM on the deleteFile.php (since this is happening in the background). When deleteFile.php finished, your Ajax sucess event will be triggered, and then you can remove it from the DOM (t.hide()). I will revise my answer to include that.

Comment: Gotcha.  I saw your changes and thank you! but, I'm not gonna use the jQuery script you provided. I'm going with php. So on the deleteFile.php - I have $filename = $_GET['filename']; unlink($filename);  ---  This does remove the file from the directory.  Now I just want to remove that same file that was deleted in the directory in the XML file.  Can't I somehow use the $filename to find in the xml file and then delete that whole child (node)?  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I got it to work.  Thanks mostly from you!  I used this for my "deleteFile.php" http://pastie.org/8673164

Comment: @user1202925 sorry just saw your last question. Glad it's working!

Answer (score 0):

The key is to write your HTML properly and then write your jQuery to do the magic

Assuming your HTML is like this, give your elements class names

```
<img src="' . $child['src'] . '" class="deleteme" alt="gallery image" /><a href="#" class="clicktodelete">Delete me</a>
```

This jQuery code will do what you want. place it at the end of your file

```
<script>
    $('.clicktodelete').click(function () {
        $(this).prev('.deleteme').hide();
    });
</script>
```